# Adding columns to Mysql table using loops but excluding few values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm fairly new to mySQL. Let's say I'm adding columns to my table like so:
alter table add query but its hectic and takes time

I have a table with column  stockvalue.I want to create columns named stockvalue_1 stocvalue_2 till stockvalue_99,but the numbers ending with 0 shouldn't come up ... eg: stockvalue_20 should'nt come. 
 alter table ass query but its hectic and takes time

Comment: No, no, no, no, no! This is horrible table design - don't do it!

Comment: @juergend Can you please go through this link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558068/how-to-loop-in-mysql